# Adding arrays to global array using multiprocessing

Tags: python, arrays, multithreading, python-multiprocessing

I've a global NumPy array **ys_final** and have defined a function that generates an array **ys**.  The **ys** array will be generated based on an input parameter and I want to add these **ys** arrays to the global array, i.e `ys_final = ys_final + ys`.
The order of addition doesn't matter so I want to use ***Pool.apply_async()*** from the multiprocessing library but I can't write to the global array. The code for reference is:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

ys_final = np.zeros(len)
def ys_genrator(i):
    #code to generate ys array
    return ys
pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())
for i in range(3954):
    ys_final = ys_final + pool.apply_async(ys_genrator, args=(i)).get()
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

The above block of code keeps on running forever and nothing happens. I've tried ***mp.Process** also and still I face the same problem. There I defined a target function that directly adds to the global array but it is also not working as the block keeps running forever. Reference:

```
def func(i):
    #code to generate ys
    global ys_final
    ys_final = ys_final + ys

for i in range(3954):
    p = mp.Process(target=func, args=(i,))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

Any suggestions will be really helpful.

EDIT:
My **ys_genrator** is a function for linear interpolation. Based on the parameter *i* which is an index for rows in a 2D image, the function creates an array of interpolated amplitudes that will be superimposed with all the interpolated amplitudes from the image, so `ys` need to be added to `ys_final`
The variable `len` is the length of the interpolated array, which is same for all rows.

For reference, a simpler version of `ys_genrator(i)` is as follows:

```py
def ys_genrator(i):
    ys = np.ones(10)*i
    return ys
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few points:

1. `pool.apply_async(ys_genrator, args=(i))` needs to be `pool.apply_async(ys_genrator, args=(i,))`. Note the comma after the `i`.
2. `pool.apply_async(ys_genrator, args=(i,)).get()` is exactly equivalent to `pool.apply(ys.genrator, args=(i,))`. That is, you will block because of your immediate call to `get` and you will have absolutely no parallism. You would need to do all your calls to `pool.apply_async` and save the returned `AsyncResult` instances and only then call `get` on these instances.
3. If you are running under Windows, you will have a problem. The code that creates new processes must be within a block governed by `if __name__ == '__main__':`
4. If you are running under something like Jupyter Notebook or iPython you will have a problem. The worker function, `ys_genrator`, would need to be in an external file and imported.
5. Using `apply_async` for submitting a lot of tasks is inefficient. You are better of using `imap` or `imap_unordered` where the tasks get submitted in "chunks" and you can process the results one by one as they become available. But you must choose a "suitable" *chunksize* argument.
6. Any code you have at the global level, such as `ys_final = np.zeros(len)` will be executed by every sub-process if you are running under Windows, and this can be wasteful if the subprocesses do not need to "see" this variable. If they do need to see this variable, be aware that each process in the pool will be working with its own copy of the variable so it better be a read-only usage. Even then, it can be very wasteful of storage if the variable is large. There are ways of sharing such a variable across the processes but it is not perfectly clear whether you need to (you haven't even defined variable `len`). So it is difficult to give you improved code. However, it appears that your worker function does not need to "see" `ys_final`, so I will take a shot at an improved solution.
7. But be aware that if your function `ys_genrator` is very trivial, nothing will be gained by using multiprocessing because there is overhead in both creating the processing pool and in passing arguments from one process to another. Also, if `ys_genrator` is using `numpy`, this can also be a source of problems since `numpy` uses multiprocessing for some of its own functions and you are better off not mixing `numpy` with your own multiprocessing.

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np

SIZE = 3

def ys_genrator(i):
    #code to generate ys array
    # for this dummy example all SIZE entries will end up with the same result:
    ys = [i] * SIZE # for example: [1, 1, 1]
    return ys

def compute_chunksize(poolsize, iterable_size):
    chunksize, remainder = divmod(iterable_size, 4 * poolsize)
    if remainder:
        chunksize += 1
    return chunksize

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ys_final = np.zeros(SIZE)
    n_iterations = 3954
    poolsize = min(mp.cpu_count(), n_iterations)
    chunksize = compute_chunksize(poolsize, n_iterations)
    print('poolsize =', poolsize, 'chunksize =', chunksize)
    pool = mp.Pool(poolsize)
    for result in pool.imap_unordered(ys_genrator, range(n_iterations), chunksize):
        ys_final += result
    print(ys_final)
```

Prints:

```
poolsize = 8 chunksize = 124
[7815081. 7815081. 7815081.]
```

**Update**

You can also just use:

```py
    for result in pool.map(ys_genrator, range(n_iterations)):
        ys_final += result
```

The issue is that when you use method `map`, the method wants to compute an efficient `chunksize` argument based on the size of the iterable argument (see my `compute_chunksize` function above, which is essentially what `pool.map` will use). But to do this, is will have to first convert the iterable to a list to get its size. If `n_iterations` is very large, this is not very efficient, although it's probably not an major issue for a size of 3954. Still, you would be better off using my `compute_chunksize` function in this case since you know the size of the iterable and then pass the *chunksize* argument explicitly to `map` as I have done in the code using `imap_unordered`.

Comment: Thank you for the input, I updated my code keeping the important things that you mentioned in mind, and it's somewhat working, but not exactly as supposed to. The `pool.map()` part appends the generated `ys` files to `ys_final` but I want them to get added together like the addition of two arrays.

Say if, `a=[1,2,3]` and `b=[4,5,6]` then `a+b=[5,7,9]`

Thanks again for the info.

Comment: In that case, see my updated answer and especially note number 5.

Comment: I've updated the answer one more time to use `+=`.

Comment: Thank you, the above solution works. The problem that I faced while scaling it up is the memory issue. The ys array is a floating array of containing 40*44100 elements.  With `n_itrations=3954` it exceeds the physical memory of my system as the result are Stored in an array. The solution that I thought is that to run the iterations in small chunks of 659 iterations, and I still ran into problems. Could you suggest something please? Thank you.

Comment: I can't answer your question because I don't know enough about your problem. If this answer addressed your original question about how to do this *in general*, then you should *accept* the answer and post a *new* question with the multiprocessing code you are using, what you tried to resolve it (how you broke it up into chunks) and the *actual* `ys_generator` function you are using. Then perhaps somebody might have a constructive idea.

Comment: When you've posted the question, add a comment to your question addressed to me with @Booboo so I know and if I am free I will take a look at it.